# Qt qml - how to use component in its definition?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have to implement `TreeView` in `qml`. Basically because each subtree is just `TreeView` itself, i want to use `TreeView` component in `TreeView` definition (this is that `Repeater` on the end).

This is part of code where i reference the component i am defining.

You can see that `rootDelegate` is actually `id` of the `Component`.

Problem is Qt gives error **Unable to assign QQuickRow to QQmlComponent**

```
 Repeater {
    model: childrens
    delegate: rootDelegate
 }
```

**TreeView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0


Component {

    id: rootDelegate

    Column {

        Row {

            id: itemControl
            spacing: 2

            Rectangle {

                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#EEEEEE" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#404040" }
                }

                width: openChar.implicitWidth
                height: openChar.implicitHeight - 6
                radius: 3

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                }

                Text {
                    id: openChar
                    text: "+"
                    color: "black"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                height: 1
                color: "#A0A0A0"
                width: 10
                anchors.verticalCenter:  parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Text {
                text: model.text
                color: "white"
            }

        }

        Repeater {
            model: childrens
            delegate: rootDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a `var` property

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a Сomponent recursively in itself, it is not allowed in Qml